# Design Principles for Applying Configurations to Multiple Destinations

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns

Do solid design principles exist for a scenario where one would have a dashboard for applying configurations to multiple different locations?

As an example - let's say you have a dashboard to monitor and configure 10 different weather sensors. Each sensor can either be

- "OFF"
- "ON"
- "ON for 1 hour a day"

i.e. each of the 10 sensors have 3 different modes they can be set up in.

The question is: how would one approach designing a dashboard to toggle configurations for the entire sensor array? Seems like applying individual configurations would turn into a huge pain with larger number of sensors (e.g. 100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to consider how important the action is. If let's say it's a wifi extender; it is a one time setup so the on/off switch won't be used that much (because why would you want to turn off a wifi extender)?. The on/off settings will then (logically) be placed a little bit more hidden because it's not that relevant.

> Question is how would one approach designing a dashboard to toggle
>   configurations for the entire sensor array? Seems like applying
>   individual configurations would turn into a huge pain with larger
>   number of sensors (e.g. 100).

thats exactly what you want to avoid right? To visualise large amounts of data (ex. 100 sensors), it is a common practice to put them in a table. With a (good) data table, you can bulk select and do bulk actions like turning all sensors on or off...

I can't really guess how relevant the 'modes' are in your weather sensor but i can provide you with some examples the way I would do it ;)

[image]

Comment: Jumping off of this, it might be useful to allow users to create groups, which then have the bulk selector option. So if they create a group "garage", there should be a single toggle switch that can turn off everything in the "garage".